# invoke-sqlcmd - can I change the ApplicationName?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm running queries against SQL servers using invoke-sqlcmd and invoke-sqlcmd2.

Is there a way to change the ApplicationName that it runs as?  When I run a profiler trace, I see the queries are run by ".Net SqlClient Data Provider", and I'd like to change that.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, futzed with the invoke-sqlcmd2 script by Chad Miller and came up with this:

Line 45, after "datarow" I added a comma, then:

```
[Parameter(Position=9, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$ApplicationName='Powershell'
```

Then modified the connection strings (about line 54):

```
if ($Username) 
{ $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Application Name={5};Trusted_Connection=False;Connect Timeout={4}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$Username,$Password,$ConnectionTimeout,$ApplicationName } 
else 
{ $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Application Name={3};Connect Timeout={2}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$ConnectionTimeout,$ApplicationName }
```

The default Appname is now "Powershell", but can be changed by using the -ApplicationName parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Include `Application Name=MyAppName;` in your connection string, and that will be what shows up in the profiler.

Comment: There is no way to specify a connectionstring with `Invoke-SQLCmd` or [`Invoke-SQLCmd2`](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7985b7ef-ed89-4dfd-b02a-433cc4e30894) as far as I can tell. So you'd have to use System.Data.SqlClient directly.

Comment: @alroc thanks.  Was worth a shot. May have to mod invoke-sqlcmd/2 and add that to it. THANKS.